# Capture image and submit to other function in kivy python

Tags: python, opencv, kivy, kivy-language

How to call other function on button click and return an image from that function?

Comment: Post a specific example with a specific question about the part you can't work out. If you can't work out more than one part, narrow the question down to a single component. For instance, if you don't know how to run a function when a button is pressed, ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

See [OpenCV UI documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html). Here is an example to store left clicked locations on an image:

```
locs = []
global locs

def clicked_point(event, x, y, flag, image):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        coords.append((x, y))

cv2.namedWindow('window-name')
cv2.imshow('window-name', img)

cv2.setMouseCallback('window-name', clicked_point, img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You could define another function that does what you want.

Comment: I need in kivy, when a button is pressed it should display another image from other function, kindly provide code as im new to this